# Breeze.WebAPI.EFContextProvider "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I originally thought this error was specific to Entity Framework. But now think it has something to do with BreezeJS's EFContextProvider.

I have a linq query that works fine in both Entity Framework and Linq-to-sql:

```
var dc = new EFContextProvider<MyEntities>();
var query = 
    (from t1 in dc.Context.Table1
    where (from t2 in dc.Context.Table2 select t2.TypeID).Distinct().Contains(t1.TypeID)
    select t1);
```

On execution of this query, I get the error: **Unable to create a constant value of type "Table2"**

But, if I execute the query directly against Entity Framework:

```
var dc = new MyEntities();
var query = 
    (from t1 in dc.Table1
    where (from t2 in dc.Table2 select t2.TypeID).Contains(t1.TypeID)
    select t1);
```

The query succeeds.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks Nick,

We were able to reproduce the problem and are investigating.

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing and investigating the issue, we found that the error is happening in EF and we are unable to fix it. However, we found that this behavior is due to the "dotted" path within the query

```
dc.Context.Table2
```

and the workaround is to simply avoid such:

```
var dc = new EFContextProvider<MyEntities>();
var dc1 = dc_breeze.Context;

var query = 
    (from t1 in dc.Context.Table1
    where (from t2 in dc1.Table2 select t2.TypeID).Distinct().Contains(t1.TypeID)
    select t1);
```

Comment: Just to add something - I had the same problem and the posted answer above contains a typo. `var dc1 = dc_breeze.Context;` should be `var dc1 = dc.breeze.Context;`